# jQuery if element has class do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to toggle whether tabs will be displayed based on whether or not the matched list item has a class of active. I've tried multiple different approaches with if statements and .hasClass but cannot get it to behave as I wish! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of one of my attempts:

```
$( "#indexHero" ).onClick(function(){
  $("#tabNo1.active"){
    $( "#testID1, #testID2" ).addClass( "hideMe" );
    $( "#testID3" ).removeClass( "hideMe" );
  }
});
```

Comment: *"`$( "#indexHero" ).onClick(...`"* What's that? It's not jQuery.... jQuery would be `.click(...` or `.on("click", ...` (or in days gone by, `.bind("click", ...`).

Comment: You have `.hasClass()` for that purposes, it will return a boolean. By the way, I would replace `.onClick(function(){});` by `.on('click', function(){});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with `length` property or else Use `.hasClass()` in jquery

```
$( "#indexHero" ).click(function(){
 if($("#tabNo1.active").length > 0){
   $( "#testID1, #testID2" ).addClass( "hideMe" );
   $( "#testID3" ).removeClass( "hideMe" );
 }
});
```

or

```
if($("#tabNo1").hasClass("active")){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `hasClass()`

```
   $( "#indexHero" ).click(function(){
      if ($('#tabNo1').hasClass('active')) {
        $( "#testID1, #testID2" ).addClass( "hideMe" );
        //} else {
        $( "#testID3" ).removeClass( "hideMe" );
       }
      }):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( "#indexHero" ).click(function(){
   if($("#tabNo1").hasClass("active"))
   {
      $( "#testID1, #testID2" ).addClass( "hideMe" );
      $( "#testID3" ).removeClass( "hideMe" );
   }
});
```